# sql select column from except result

Tags: sql, sql-server, except

I try to get column from except result, but all the time have error "Incorect syntax near ')'" even when I put Select * in first select. I work on SQL Management Studio. My code looks like

```
select ColumnResult from (
            select col1 as ColumnResult, col2 as Column2Result, col3 as Column3Result
            from SourceTable 
            except
            select col1 as ColumnResult, col2 as Column2Result, col3 as Column3Result
            from SourceTable2)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: That's valid ANSI SQL, verified with http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I try to do it in SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give you subquery an alias:

```
select ColumnResult from (
            select col1 as ColumnResult, col2 as Column2Result, col3 as Column3Result
            from SourceTable 
            except
            select col1 as ColumnResult, col2 as Column2Result, col3 as Column3Result
            from SourceTable2) AS Src
```

Comment: Not needed in ANSI SQL.

Comment: I'll take your word for that. It does fit the error description.

Comment: Seems to be SQL Server.

Comment: @liquid the best way to say thank you on SO is to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You get error because each table have its own alias name so do it

```
select A.ColumnResult from (
                select col1 as ColumnResult, col2 as Column2Result, col3 as Column3Result
                from SourceTable 
                except
                select col1 as ColumnResult, col2 as Column2Result, col3 as Column3Result
                from SourceTable2) as A
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?